# Stick label within input field that does not change when typed. (No placeholder). HTML/JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please see screenshot below, on the left side is what I'm currently getting and on the right side is what i want to achieve **without using any plugins or html5 attributes**

[image]

The way left side of screen happens is I have 2 input fields out of which 1 has the value `Username:` and the other one is hidden. When I focus `Username:` input field, that field gets hidden and the new field becomes visible. On blurr event the vice-verse happens.

JS Code:

```
$(document).on('focus', '#login .placeholder', function() {
    var inEl = $('#user_name');
    if (inEl && ! inEl.is(':visible')) {
       $(this).hide();
       inEl.show().focus();
    }
});

$(document).on('blur', '#user_name', function() {
    if ($(this).val().length <= 0) {
        var placeHolderElement = $('#login .placeholder');
        placeHolderElement.show();
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show your current code, and if you can, make a fiddle?

Comment: I dont know how to make a fiddle but i will post the code

Comment: Is this what you're trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/ZEpBX/

Comment: @tymeJV no that i have it, I want UserName to stick with input as i type text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/emasuj/1/edit

```
<label>
  Username:
  <input type="text" />    
</label>
```

CSS:

```
input{
  border:none;
  background:#eee;
}
label{
  color:#777;
  padding:10px;
  background:#eee;
  border-radius:5px;
}
```

If you want to change bg colors on focus here is an example how to do it with a bit of jQ: 
http://jsbin.com/emasuj/2/edit

Comment: @GGio :) you're welcome! Here is an example how to change colors on focus: http://jsbin.com/emasuj/2/edit